# C++ Builder 5 and WinAPI, TransparentColor

Tags: c++, windows

What could be the alternative to TransparentColor and Transparent properties coming from CBuilder6, but absents of TForm in CBuilder5...

any WINAPI clue ?

DH

Comment: So I'm not the only one in the world still using bcb5

Comment: Bcb5 is clearly the top

Answer (score 1):

- [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) can specify one color as a transparent color.
- `SetWindowRgn` can also be used (and must be used on versions before Win2000). It however requires you to build the mask by yourself.

Comment: I will check that.... and come back for more

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best answer :

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) 

{ this->Align = ::alClient;
  this->Color = TColor(RGB(255, 255, 255)); 
 
 ::SetWindowLongPtr(this->Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED); 
 ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this->Handle, ::ColorToRGB(this->Color), 255, LWA_COLORKEY); 
}
```

Notice that I was compelled to have the TForm's Align property set to ::alClient...so the TForm became clickable even with LayerAttribute set to a COLOR_REF...

Thanks all...
That, now, is usable...

DH